# Döbereiner's Law Explanation Required?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I wanted to ask why do the middle elements in the triads have masses average to the other elements in the [Döbereiner triads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%B6bereiner%27s_triads) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've marked some of the Döbereiner triads on the periodic table:

[image: Döbereiner triads]

In all cases the atomic number changes by the same amount between the first to second and the second to third members of the triad. That means the atomic number of the middle element is exactly the mean of the first and third elements.

The ratio of the number of neutrons to protons is approximately constant, at least for the lighter elements, so the number of neutrons in the middle element is *approximately* the mean of the other two elements. Since the atomic mass is the sum of the number of protons and neutrons that means the atomic mass of the middle element is also *approximately* the mean of the other two.

But note that this only works in some cases. For example the triad Boron, Aluminium, Gallium doesn't work because we have the first transition row in between Aluminium and Gallium. Likewise Titanium, Zirconium, Hafnium doesn't work because we have the first row of the actinides between Zirconium and Hafnium.

So while Döbereiner's observation is true in some cases we shouldn't attach too much significance to it, other than of course that it is a symptom of a deeper underlying structure.

Answer (score 0):

Döbereiner discovered six groups of three elements in 1829. He noticed that some physical properties of elements (such as atomic weight and density) in a triad tended to follow a trend in which the value of the middle element in the triad is the arithmetic mean of the values for that property of the other two elements. Besides the physical properties, the elements in the triad also follow a trend in chemical properties. In the first triads, for example, all three elements are alkali metals and are placed in group 1 of the modern periodic table. They form hydroxides (LiOH, NaOH, KOH), chlorides (LiCl, NaCl, KCl), and hydrides (LiH, NaH, KH).
[image]

Atomic Mass (1850)
$\left.\begin{array}{lc}\mathrm{Li} & 7 \\ \mathrm{Na} & 23 \\ \mathrm{~K} & 39\end{array}\right] \rightarrow \frac{7+39}{2}=23$
$\left.\begin{array}{lc}\mathrm{Ca} & 40 \\ \mathrm{Sr} & 87 \\ \mathrm{Ba} & 137\end{array}\right] \rightarrow \frac{40+137}{2}=88.5$
$\left.\begin{array}{lr}\text { P } & 31 \\ \text { As } & 75 \\ \text { Sb } & 122\end{array}\right] \rightarrow \frac{31+122}{2}=76.5$
$\left.\begin{array}{lr}\mathrm{S} & 32 \\ \mathrm{Se} & 78 \\ \mathrm{Te} & 128\end{array}\right] \rightarrow \frac{32+128}{2}=80$
$\left.\begin{array}{cc}\mathrm{Cl} & 35.5 \\ \mathrm{Br} & 80 \\ \mathrm{I} & 127\end{array}\right] \rightarrow \frac{35.5+127}{2}=81.25$

Atomic Number
$\left.\begin{array}{cc}\mathrm{Li} & 3 \\ \mathrm{Na} & 11 \\ \mathrm{~K} & 19\end{array}\right] \rightarrow \frac{3+19}{2}=11$
$\left.\begin{array}{ll}\mathrm{Ca} & 20 \\ \mathrm{Sr} & 38 \\ \mathrm{Ba} & 56\end{array}\right] \rightarrow \frac{20+56}{2}=38$
$\left.\begin{array}{ll}\text { P } & 15 \\ \text { As } & 33 \\ \text { Sb } & 51\end{array}\right] \rightarrow \frac{15+51}{2}=33$
$\left.\begin{array}{ll}\mathrm{S} & 16 \\ \mathrm{Se} & 34 \\ \mathrm{Te} & 52\end{array}\right] \rightarrow \frac{16+52}{2}=34$
$\left.\begin{array}{rr}\mathrm{Cl} & 17 \\ \mathrm{Br} & 35 \\ \mathrm{I} & 53\end{array}\right] \rightarrow \frac{17+53}{2}=35$

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\text { Predicted vs actual atomic mass of the central atom of each triad }\\
\begin{array}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline {\text { Triad name }{ }} & {\text { Elements and atomic masses }{ }} \\
 & \text { Element 1 } & \text { Element 2 } & \text { Element 3 } \\
& \text { Mass } & \text { Mean of 1 and 3 } & \text { Mass } \\
& & \text { Actual mass } & \\
\hline \text { Alkali-forming elements } & \text { Lithium } & \text { Sodium } & \text { Potassium } \\
& 6.941 \mathrm{u} & 22.989769 \mathrm{u} & 39.0983 \mathrm{u} \\
& & 23.01965 \mathrm{u} & \\
\hline \text { Alkaline-earth-forming elements } & \text { Calcium } & \text { Strontium } & \text { Barium } \\
\text { } & 40.078 \mathrm{u} & 87.62 \mathrm{u} & 137.327 \mathrm{u} \\
& & 88.7025 \mathrm{u} & \\
\hline \text { Salt-forming elements } & \text { Chlorine } & \text { Bromine } & \text { lodine } \\
& 35.470 \mathrm{u} & 79.904 \mathrm{u} & 126.904 \mathrm{u} \\
\hline \text { Acid-forming elements } & & 81.187 \mathrm{u} & \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$